# Getting "No such file or directory" for java installation when trying to build a hbase docker image

Tags: java, linux, docker, dockerfile, hbase

I'm trying to dockerize a hbase setup on a devcloud instance but I am getting this error when I'm trying to run the `start-hbase.sh` file

```
 /hbase-2.4.7/bin/hbase: line 794: /jdk1.8.0_281/bin/java: No such file or directory
 /hbase-2.4.7/bin/hbase: line 794: /jdk1.8.0_281/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

I checked and I saw that the path is available so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Below are the contents of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.8

USER root

RUN passwd -u root

RUN   apk update \                                                                                                                                                              
&&   apk add ca-certificates wget \                                                                                                                                             
&&   update-ca-certificates   # This line may not do anything
# unlock root

RUN apk add bash

RUN wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" https://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/GetFile/1.8.0_281-b09/89d678f2be164786b292527658ca1605/linux-i586/jdk-8u281-linux-x64.tar.gz

RUN tar -xvf jdk-8u281-linux-x64.tar.gz


ENV JAVA_HOME jdk1.8.0_281

ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

# Install Apache HBase
ENV HBASE_VER 2.4.7

RUN wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/hbase/2.4.7/hbase-2.4.7-bin.tar.gz

RUN tar -xvf hbase-2.4.7-bin.tar.gz

RUN  "./hbase-2.4.7/bin/start-hbase.sh"
```

Comment: _`/jdk1.8.0_281/bin/java` "I saw that the path is available"_ - really? Is the `jdk1.8.0_281` folder really at the root?

Comment: Yes, I did try cd'ing into ```/jdk1.8.0_281/bin/``` and listing the contents and I did see the java folder

Answer (score 0):

You are better defining a working directory for your main application layer which is *HBase* in this case and separate your dependencies in explicitly defined absolute paths.

In particular, you should copy your `JDK` extracted folder to an absolute path:

```
RUN tar -xvf jdk-8u281-linux-x64.tar.gz

RUN mv ./jdk1.8.0_281 /usr/lib/jvm/

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281

ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Comment: I tried that but it's still not working